# Slicing a range from a pandas dataframe column using loc

Tags: python, pandas, slice, pandas-loc

I tried to extract a value range from a pandas column using `loc` but I fail with:

```
df.loc[0.5<df['a']<1.5, ['a']]
```

What is the correct pandas way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df.loc[df['a'].between(0.5, 1.5, inclusive=False), ['a']]
```

Or chain conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df.loc[(df['a'] > 0.5) & (df['a'] < 1.5), ['a']]
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with select `a` to one column `DataFrame`:

```
df[['a']].query("0.5 < a < 1.5")
#alternative
#df.query("0.5 < a < 1.5")[['a']]
```